# Помощь по поводу on_member_update и спец. списка

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Всем привет! Столкнулся с двумя проблемами.

1. Добавления двух нужных функций в on_member_update, мне нужно сделать так, что бы писалось, кто выдал роль, и какая роль была выдана собственно говоря, почитав доки, нашел, что у on_member_update only before, after, как мне собственно говоря добавить данные функции?
2. Не выводит нужных людей в списке, команда должна выводить людей с определенной ролью, но не выводит ничего, так же если поможете разобраться, как сделать так, что бы эти люди были в mention буду очень благодарен.

Ниже прилагаю все нужные коды, а так же как они выглядят.

Код 1:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.roles != after.roles:
        channel = client.get_channel(729733881129074768)
        emb = discord.Embed(title = '', description = f'**Обновление ролей пользователя -  {before.mention}**', colour = discord.Color.red())
        emb.add_field(name = '**Роли до**', value = [r.mention for r in before.roles] ) 
        emb.add_field(name = '**Роли после**', value = [r.mention for r in  after.roles] ) 

        await channel.send(embed = emb)
```

[image: Скриншот]

Код 2:

```py
@client.command()
async def members_info(ctx):
    server_members = ctx.guild.members 
    data = ("\n".join([member for member in server_members if "Следящий за Discord" in member.roles]))
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f'Участники сервера', description = f"{data}", color = discord.Color.purple())
    await ctx.send( embed = embed )
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Чутка коряво вставил скриншоты, по этому приложу просто ссылку на скриншот.
1 - https://imgur.com/a/44hSQjC
2 - https://imgur.com/a/ln14M4p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Используйте данные из [лога аудита](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/api.html#discord.Guild.audit_logs)

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if before.roles != after.roles:
        channel = client.get_channel(729733881129074768)
        emb = discord.Embed(description = f'**Обновление ролей пользователя -  {before.mention}**', colour = discord.Color.red())
        emb.add_field(name = '**Роли до**', value = ", ".join([r.mention for r in before.roles])) 
        emb.add_field(name = '**Роли после**', value = ", ".join([r.mention for r in after.roles])) 
        async for event in before.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.member_role_update): # https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/api.html#discord.AuditLogAction.member_role_update
            # event: AuditLogEntry — https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/api.html#discord.AuditLogEntry
            if getattr(event.target, "id", None) != before.id:
                # изменение ролей пользователя прошло без записи в логах аудита, или в лог аудита попала другая запись перед выполнением текущего участка кода
                continue
            emb.add_field(name="Изменённые роли", value = ", ".join([getattr(r, "mention", r.id) for r in event.before.roles or event.after.roles]))  # event.before, event.after: AuditLogDiff — https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/api.html#discord.AuditLogDiff 
            emb.add_field(name="Модератор", value = event.user)
            break
        await channel.send(embed = emb)
```

2. `member.roles` - список объектов типа `discord.Role`, а не список строк.

```py
@client.command()
async def members_info(ctx):
    server_members = ctx.guild.members 
    data = "\n".join([member.mention for member in server_members if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Следящий за Discord") in member.roles])
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Участники сервера", description=data, color=discord.Color.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

*примечание: рекомендую получать роль по ID через `guild.get_role(ID)`, вместо получения роли по имени. Это значительно снизит риск возможных проблем если появится вторая роль с таким же названием:*

```py
@client.command()
async def members_info(ctx):
    server_members = ctx.guild.members 
    data = "\n".join([member.mention for member in server_members if ctx.guild.get_role(565686928782228899) in member.roles])
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Участники сервера", description=data, color=discord.Color.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Привет! 
Попробовал данный способ, который Вы предложили, но выходит уже другая ошибка, что странно, ведь на сервере данных участников 15+ штук

`CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Member found`

Comment: С кол-вом участников это никак не связано, тут мой косяк, `str.join()` принимает только строки. Исправил ответ, так же можно использовать str(member) для получения строки вида `UserName#0000`

Comment: Теперь все работает, спасибо!